# Unique tabbar design

Tags: objective-c, uitabbar

I need to code a unique tabbar with the center tab being much higher than the other tabs, but, the region to the left and right of the higher tab not being part of the bar.

[image: super crude artist rendering]

Looking for a suggestion where to start with this, have never had a tabbar protrude into the view space above.

Comment: One way of doing is to apply a mask over the selected tab.

Comment: Thanks for the response, can you say a bit more on the subject, not seeing how a mask gives me what is needed.

Comment: a mask can be done using many ways. One way is to create a uiview and add it right infront of the tab, and give the custom appearance for that uiview

Comment: I will post a sample code after I get a working prototype.

Comment: i posted my answer, p[lease check it @Rob

Answer (score 0):

A `UITabBarController` is just a `UIViewController` that contains several other `UIViewControllers` and manages which one is currently present.

It places the `view` of its child view controllers as a `subview` of its own `view` and then places a `UIView` over them in the for of a tab bar.

It would be relatively easy to recreate this with your own custom controller.

You need an array of view controllers to manage as the "tabs" or even just a specific view controller for each tab. You need a view to act as your tab bar.

The view would have buttons on it that then trigger actions in the controller. Thos actions can then change the currently displayed tab.

It sounds like a lot of work but it really isn't and is much less hacky than trying to change images outside of the tab bar bounds etc...

Answer (score -1):

**Note:** You need to find the center tab, and do the same thing for the center tab.

You can try this way to make a custom view appear on the tab bar when you select a tab bar item: Or You can follow another different way to  raise the selected tab bar item from this [link:](http://idevrecipes.com/2010/12/16/raised-center-tab-bar-button/)

In your tab bar `viewDidAppear` method, set the tags to the tab bar items:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];


    [[[self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0]tabBarItem]setTag:0];
    [[[self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1]tabBarItem]setTag:1];

}
```

and when you select a tab bar item, this method will get hit, so you customise this method:

```
-(void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item{

if (item.tag==0) {

    [[self.view viewWithTag:1]removeFromSuperview];

    mycustomView  *  maskView= [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"customView" owner:self options:nil] firstObject];

    [maskView  setFrame:CGRectMake(tabBar.frame.origin.x, tabBar.frame.origin.y+tabBar.frame.size.height-80, maskView.frame.size.width,maskView.frame.size.height)];

   [maskView setAlpha:0.5];
    maskView.tag=2;
    [maskView setColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:maskView];

}

if (item.tag==1) {

    [[self.view viewWithTag:2]removeFromSuperview];

 mycustomView *  maskView= [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"customView" owner:self options:nil] firstObject];

    [maskView  setFrame:CGRectMake(tabBar.frame.origin.x+tabBar.frame.size.width/2, tabBar.frame.origin.y+tabBar.frame.size.height-80, maskView.frame.size.width,maskView.frame.size.height)];

    [maskView setAlpha:0.5];
    [maskView setColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    maskView.tag=1;

    [self.view addSubview:maskView];

}
```

}

Here is the custom UIView file:

```
@interface mycustomView : UIView

@property (nonatomic,assign) UIColor *color;

@end
```

and custom view .m file:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)frame {

    UIBezierPath* bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [bezierPath moveToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 0.5, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 39.5)];
    [bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(7.5, 87.5) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 1.5, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 80.5) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(7.5, 87.5)];
    [bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(213.5, 87.5)];
    [bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 206.5, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 39.5)];
    [bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 173.5, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 11.5)];
    [bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(104.5, 6.5)];
    [bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 38.5, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 11.5)];
    [bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 0.5, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 39.5)];
    [self.color setFill];
    [bezierPath fill];
    [UIColor.blackColor setStroke];
    bezierPath.lineWidth = 1;
    [bezierPath stroke];


}
```

The result will be something like this:

[image]

Please note, you need to take care in giving different tag values to the views you add on each tab bar item,and calculate the proper frame size for each custom view, that fits perfectly on the tab bar item. This example, I wrote the code for only 2 tabs.

Comment: I really think the `tag` property should be removed from `UIView` it only ever leads to bad design.

Comment: so far it is the only way i feel easy to remove the uiview. But please provide more info about why using tags is a bad design ?

Comment: I guess a better way (slightly better) would be to keep a reference to the views you are adding and removing. A better way still would be to create a subclass that adds and removes the views itself. Or something.

Comment: You could create a dictionary of` `[ViewController: UITabBarItem]` or something.